# How to rotate plot along x-axis in Scilab?

Tags: plot, scilab

Please can anyone tell me how to rotate it along the x-axis .

Rotate curve C1(u) about X-axis to generate the set of curves at a step size of **pi/100** given by

```
theta=0:%pi/100:%pi/2.
```

```
ABC = [0 0 1;1 1 1;1/4 1/2 1] \ [0 0 0;1 0 0;1/2 1/2 0];
A = ABC(1,:);
B = ABC(2,:);
C = ABC(3,:);
u = linspace(0,1,100);
C1 = A'*u.^2+B'*u+C'*ones(u);
param3d(C1(1,:),C1(2,:),C1(3,:));
```

Comment: Hmm, did you heard about rotation matrices ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet let me check over it .

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet thnx bro that really help me a lot .  :)

Comment: If you managed to do the job in Scilab please answer your own question it would be a pleasure to upvote it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
ABC = [0 0 1;1 1 1;1/4 1/2 1] \ [0 0 0;1 0 0;1/2 1/2 0];
A = ABC(1,:);
B = ABC(2,:);
C = ABC(3,:);
u = linspace(0,1,100);
C1 = A'*u.^2+B'*u+C'*ones(u);
param3d(C1(1,:),C1(2,:),C1(3,:));

theta = %pi/100;
R = [1 0 0
     0 cos(theta) -sin(theta) 
     0 sin(theta)  cos(theta)];

for i=1:50
    C1 = R*C1;
    param3d(C1(1,:),C1(2,:),C1(3,:));
end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me why my code is showing different fig then urs .??

Comment: First, you have to write sin(theta(i)) and cos(theta(i)) and the rotation matrix operates on column vectors by multiplication on the left. In ABCD the vectors are stacked as lines.

Comment: Hence write `ABC=ABCD*r'`

Comment: Ya i have changed sin(i) to sin(theta(i)) and cos one too . I have already written ABC = ABCD*r .

Comment: BTW your idea to rotate the points A,B,C is neat ! With your modified code I got the same curves as my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
clc;clear;
theta=0:%pi/100:%pi/2;
n=length(theta);
for i=1:n
x=sin(theta(i));
y=cos(theta(i));
r=[1 0 0;0 y -x;0 x y];
ABCD = [0 0 1;1 1 1;1/4 1/2 1] \ [0 0 0;1 0 0;1/2 1/2 0];
ABC = ABCD*r';
A = ABC(1,:);
B = ABC(2,:);
C = ABC(3,:);
u = linspace(0,1,100);
C1 = A'*u.^2+B'*u+C'*ones(u);
param3d(C1(1,:),C1(2,:),C1(3,:));
end
```

Comment: we still have to declare i early . means we need to declare the for loop early where we assigned x value .

Comment: @Stéphane Now this is really working fine . Thanks for the help :). But why we use apostrophe symbol in ABCD*r' ?

Comment: The apostrophe means transposition

Comment: The line `ABCD = [0 0 1;1 1 1;1/4 1/2 1] \ [0 0 0;1 0 0;1/2 1/2 0];`can be outside the loop as well as `u = linspace(0,1,100);`

Comment: I really dont know about that . Thanks a lot . :)

Comment: Can you validate my first answer ?